# HTC Sensation fastboot unknown device

Tags: rooting, fastboot, htc-sensation

I experience problems trying to root my HTC Sensation.

I turned **USB Debugging ON**, checked that **Fast boot** is turned **ON** in **Settings > Power** section and connected phone to PC.

[image: USB Debugging turned on]

My device was recognized successfully
[image: Device was recognized]

Also it was shown in adb list

```
C:\sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
List of devices attached
HT15LVXXXXXX    device
```

Now i took out my battery, inserted that back, pushed and hold Power button and Volume Down and voila, i am in **HBOOT**.

I pressed Power button once, choosing **FASTBOOT**
[image: FASTBOOT]

My phone connected to Windows, but this time device was **not recognized**.
[image: Unknown Device]

I tried to add drivers for that device manually, but it failed
[image: Failed drivers]

I even tried to add **%MyHTC%=HTCAND32.Dev, USB\UNKNOWN** to **androidusb.inf** and then add driver manually, but device was not working anyway and **fastboot devices** command returned empty list.

I tried same operations on my Mac using fastboot-mac for that and i got same result as on Windows - device is not recognized in fastboot mode.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, two tips I can give you. 1) Fast boot in the settings has nothing to do with fastboot for flashing. The settings one is for not fully rebooting the OS to speed restarts. 2) The driver for fastboot is different than the driver for ADB. If you install HTC Sync it should install both, however. Sometimes you have to remove conflicting drivers using usbdeview or other tool.

Answer (score 2):

Hey if somebody searches for an answer to this.

I have solved it by adding a key in the registry.

In `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\usbflags\0BB40FF00100` (The "cryptic" hex-number at the end is the VID, PID and REV value of the Hardware-id you can see under Details) if that key isn't existing (mine was) create it.

Then add a Binary Value `SkipBOSDescriptorQuery` and set it to `01 00 00 00`

When I did that it "magically" worked on my Windows 10 vers 20H2 Build 19042.928 after a reconnect of the USB device.

*Why does this work?*

As far as I can deduce, this BOS Descriptor is a fairly new thing in USB 3 and was backported to USB 2.1. Windows is requesting that from the phone's USB device and that or the driver isn't new enough to consider/disable this BOSDescriptorQuery and only delivers garbage to device enumeration. The drive/OS is confused and refuses to properly work. My bet is that the driver for such of an old phone isn't worked on anymore to consider this failure mode.

Comment: Thanks!  Upvoted.  Can you explain what this does and why this works?

Comment: As far as I can deduce this BOS Descriptor is a fairly new thing in USB 3 and was backported to USB 2.1. Windows is requesting that from the phone's USB device and that or the driver isn't new enough to consider/disable this BOSDescriptorQuery and only delivers garbage to device enumeration. The drive/OS is confused and refuses to properly work. My bet is that the driver for such of an old phone isn't worked on anymore to consider this failure mode.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I added that great information to your answer.  Thank you again!

Comment: Why there is such a high activity within last couple of days about a telephone which was released 10 years ago?

Answer (score 1):

you need to unlock thebootloader first before doing anything... the screen shot shows that your phone is still locked 
you can do that on HTCDEV site